# Returning values not ending in digits based upon variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, stored-procedures, where-clause

I'm passing through a variable into my stored procedure and was writing a case statement in my WHERE clause. Normally I would write it something like this:

```
CodeID like CASE WHEN @Duration != '0' 
                THEN '%' + @Duration 
                ELSE '%' END
```

The problem, however, is that this isn't quite what I need. What I actually need is something with the logic of *IF @Duration != '0' THEN CodeID like '%' + @Duration ELSE CodeID doesn't end with a digit.*

Is this possible? I considered writing a couple of IF statements with the respective queries in each, but as there isn't a wildcard for digit, I'm having some trouble with this logic as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I actually need is something with the logic of IF @Duration != '0' THEN CodeID like '%' + @Duration ELSE CodeID doesn't end with a digit.

Use boolean logic:

```
where 
    (@duration <> '0' and CodeID like '%' + @Duration)
    or (@duration = '0' and CodeID not like '%[0-9]')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(@Duration <> '0' and codeid like '%' + @duration) or
(@Duration = '0' and codeid like '%[0-9]')
```